# How can i run multiple commands in python script

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, ncurses

How can i run multiple commands using python script

I have already written following code, but still is there any other alternative?

```
 os.system("clear")
 os.system("virtualenv -p python3 /opt/"+name)
 os.system("source /opt/"+name+"/bin/activate")
 os.system("pip install /usr/share/my-packages/*")
```

Also please let me know if there is any way that can do one of following:
-Either don't on console what is happening with commands such as: `creating virtual envirnoment.` etc.
-Or else those statements which are going to be printed on console any how i can get it in any variable so that i can use those on python-curses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try building a list:

```
commands = ['clear', 
            'virtualenv -p python3 /opt/'+name, 
            'source /opt/'+name+'/bin/activate',
            'pip install /usr/share/my-packages/*']

for command in commands:
    os.system(command)
```

This allows for easier maintenance of the commands you want to include/exclude.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1**

> How can i run multiple commands using python script

To run multiple commands, you can use the `&` to separate the command:

```
os.system("clear & "
          "virtualenv -p python3 /opt/" + name + " & "
          "source /opt/" + name + "/bin/activate" + " & "
          "pip install /usr/share/my-packages/*")
```

**Problem 2**

> Either don't on console what is happening with commands such as:
>   creating virtual envirnoment. etc.

If you don't want the comman result to be displayed on the console, you can add `> nul` to the end of the command line.

```
xcopy /s c:\source d:\target > nul
```